# Removing redirection to antivirus in a hacked web page

Tags: hacking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My server's been hacked EMERGENCY](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/my-servers-been-hacked-emergency)

After some sort of hacking, the main URL of my website now redirects to a fake antivirus page. How can I remove this thing?

Comment: It is recommended that you contact your hosting provider and explain the situation. They should be able to help you.

Comment: sooo cool! looks real! but i have linux ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your server has been compromised/defaced so I give you the same advice I gave on a similar [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/149067/find-the-source-of-malware/149082#149082):

Normally, it's very difficult to re-create all the attackers steps and the best solution is to reinstall the compromised servers and restore everything from the backups. On the other hand, you need to perform some forensics in order to figure out what has possibly happened and preventing it from happening again.

Here's a list of things worth checking:

- see if there are known
  vulnerabilities in your webserver and
  your ftp server versions
- take a look at every logfiles you
  can, especially the webserver, the
  ftp server and the system ones. In
  the webserver logfiles, check for
  posts
- are there any services running that
  you don't need? Are they accessible
  from the Internet? Shut them now,
  check their logs and check for
  possible known vulnerabilities.
- run rootkit checkers. They're not
  infalible but can lead you in the
  right direction. chkrootkit and
  especially rkhunter are the tools for
  the job
- run nmap from outside of your server
  and check if there is something
  listening on any port that shouldn't
  be.
- if you've a rrdtool trending
  application (like Cacti, Munin or
  Ganglia) take a look the graphs and
  search for a possible time frame of
  the attack.

Also, always keep this is mind:

- shut down all the services you don't
  need
- backup everything you need to rebuild
  your server and test backups on a
  regular basis
- follow the least privilege principle
- have your services updated,
  especially regarding security updates
- don't use default credentials

Hope this helps!

Comment: And by the way, they probably made the redirect on the contents of your index page. Hope this helps.

Comment: don't use the same passwords as before when you rebuild...